# Bug in WP 7 implementation of Uri.IsWellFormedUriString?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, uri

In a .NET 4 console application, and a Silverlight 4 application, the following returns `false`:

[`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)`("/test", UriKind.Absolute)`

but the same call in a Windows Phone app (7.0 or 7.1 using SDK 7.1 Beta 2 published 6/29/11) returns `true`.

Can anyone else confirm this?  Is this a bug in WP7?

*Update*

I reported this as a bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683289/uri-iswellformeduristring-returns-different-value-on-wp-7-vs-sl-4-or-net-4) and received an update today that it has been closed as "Wont' Fix".  This doesn't matter to me but I thought I would add this update just as an FYI.

Comment: I can confirm I see the same behaviour. Can not help on whether it is a bug or not though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) its a bug:

> A Boolean value that is true if the string was well-formed in accordance with RFC 3986; else false.

And the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3) says:

> absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]

So better submit this bug on  [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) under VS referencing the Tooling Version for phone development tools.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I've posted this to Connect and will update the case with their response.