# C# URI validation

Tags: c#, validation, uri

I found a few answers on StackOverflow about C# URI validator. But can somebody explain me where I'm wrong?
There are a few examples on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) and one is special. I'm not able in C# to make this valid:

> ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one

It's invalid with this method `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`

Who is wrong? C# or Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

you are wrong!

if I test it, I get

```
string _uri = "ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one";
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(_uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) == True;
```

try it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/H4k8fH

Comment: Hmm, i see. But something is wrong. I don't know what. Look at this https://i.imgur.com/WRJx780.png now i'm able make that valid in dotnetfiddle. But in my code is still unvalid and another screenshot with watch : https://i.imgur.com/ZRuyQDS.png

Comment: then your string is probably somehow different. can you double check?

Comment: yes, triple checked. I really don't understand whats going on.When i put that code into single solution without any other code. it's valid. But in that old solution is unvalid. I really don't understand. But thank you for that check in dotnetfiddle.I will try to figure out where the problem is and I will put answer here after that. But this is super weird.

Comment: what is the source of the string that contains the URI you're testing? it's somehow different when you check equality with the code snipped?

Comment: I added same code from dotnetfiddler into my solution. And look at this. It was only copied. https://i.imgur.com/mDcXywO.png

Comment: Ok, so, this is related. My project is silverlight and it's bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977325/bug-in-wp-7-implementation-of-uri-iswellformeduristring

Comment: this is a crazy find. can you use a different Uri Class or replace it by an regex? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847/regex-to-validate-uris

Comment: Yes, i will implement that regex method. It is really crazy :D regex will help :D Thank you